# Right way for initializing SQLAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, database-abstraction

Many tutorials say to create an application with `Flask(__name__)` and from there we can initialize the database with `SQLAlchemy(app)`.
However, I don't like this intrusive model, as the application itself doesn't need to know anything about the database.

I think a better approach would be creating a module called `database` and initialize the database there.

Models should `import db from database` and the app should just import the models.

However, with this approach the database module must retrieve the global app by somehow, something which I disagree.

Is there a property way to initialize the database without importing the main app?

Answer (score 2):

This is the neatest way i have found to set up the flask app:
In app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from app.settings import DevConfig
from app.extensions import api, mysqldb, marsh, mongodb 

def create_app(config=DevConfig):
    """Application factory. This is used to run the app from the root.

    :param config: Object to configure app stored in settings.py
    """
    app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])
    app.config.from_object(config)
    register_endpoints()
    register_extensions(app)  
    return app

def register_extensions(app):
    """Registration of flask components."""
    mysqldb.init_app(app)
    marsh.init_app(app)
    mongodb.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app)
```

Then in extensions.py i'd have something like this:

```
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

mysqldb = SQLAlchemy()
mongodb = PyMongo()
marsh = Marshmallow()
api = Api(prefix='/v1')
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
```

That way i have things seperate. There might be a way to loop the init_app in the extensions but then it would be less clean in my opinion.

To use I then import the db from the extensions file.